# Why is my database becoming suspect?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Here is my situation: restored a known good backup (works fine on other machines) that originated on Sql Server 2012 onto a local 2012 install. Created DB as part of the restore. No errors reported.

I am accessing it through a Node.js app, using the [Node-SqlServer](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/node-sqlserver) driver (if that makes a difference). The first time that the app tries to access the db after restore, the db goes into Suspect mode.

I tried deleting the Db restoring from scratch. Same thing.

I was able to "fix" the db by running [these commands](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/50562/20366). After that, the db runs fine (app can access and query the db witout issue). However, this seems like a less than ideal scenario.

Any ideas about what could be causing this and how I might be able to prevent it?

Computer is a laptop with a single SSD. I ran `chkdsk` and returned a clean bill of health. Note: this has happened with more than one db restore, specifically to this machine. So the circumstantial evidence points to the machine as being at fault here.

Comment: What was the output of your CHECKDB operations? http://www.johnsansom.com/simplify-your-dbcc-checkdb-output/

Comment: @JohnSansom no errors

Comment: @JohnSansom Just ran a fresh restore, and before doing anything (trying to access, fix, etc), ran `CHECKDB`. This time it shows errors. See [here](https://gist.github.com/yellis/f7fcc03bae1ff1050fb7) for output. Name of the db is 'Sinner2'.

Comment: So you have the backup of a corrupted DB. Every time you restore it, it will be corrupted. Restore does not do any sort of CHECKDB validation.

Comment: @RemusRusanu and the script [from here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/50562/20366) just fixes the corruption by itself?

Comment: You should have a closer look at DBCC CHECKDB documentation (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064.aspx for a start). The famous REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS will result in data loss for pages found corrupted. This can affect quite a few rows and you will hardly have any control on it. It's the last remedy if all other tries failed.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the help. If one of you would like to post an explanation of this as an answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: There is no magic to really fix the corruption. Ideally, the original DB should be fixed (by applying a *really* known good backup) and then obtain a new backup for you. DBCC REPAIR is just a  last resort, a desperate measure, and you have 0 guarantees that the result is correct, consistent or even usable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knowing that a CHECKDB returns errors right after restoring a backup, as stated by Remus Rusanu, you have a corrupted backup. As fixing this afterwards is usually much more painful then before, you should plan (or ask your DBA) to check the consistency of your databases on a very regular basis. I remember having anxious moments waiting for the results of a first DBCC CHECKDB for databases that have been in production for a few years, long before I started my job.

If you want to know more about corruption and DBCC, have a look at:

- How to corrupt a database, by Kendra Little: http://www.littlekendra.com/2011/01/24/corrupthexeditor/. I found it a great way to understand how things were working under the hood.
- Paul Randal's articles, for example http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/category/checkdb-from-every-angle/ . He is **THE** authority on DBCC and you can also subscribe to their newsletter. The last one has a great introduction video on corruption and how to fix it.

So check (sorry for this one) the health before, try to restore a valid backup, and if you have no other choice, try DBCC REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS. But as stated before, you'll lose data and that can even make your database unusable.